# Posting XML data to a PHP API via Phonegap/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, xml, cordova, jsonp

I've been task with building an app to check on the status of servers through a phonegap app. The trouble is the client is not giving me access to the existing API or the server. The only information he has given me is:  "You can send a POST request to the xmlUserApi.php named "request" by jQuery for example."

As I understand it, we are sending some XML in the format

```
<xmlApi>
  <action> getServerList </action>
   <auth></auth>
</xmlApi>
```

For example, from which a an XML list of all the servers is returned.

Whenever I try to POST this data to the PHP (xmlUserApi.php), nothing is returned. I feel it would be helpful to look through the PHP, but, the client won't let me.

Any help/ideas would be really appreciated

EDIT

The response I'm getting in the inspector is :

```
<form action=xmlUserApi.php method=post>
<textarea name=request cols=120 rows=30></textarea>
<input type=submit value=Request></form><br><br>86.135.213.213
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? How to communicate with your client? Because this seems to me the only solution. We certainly can't guess the API, can we? You either have an error in your request (than you should show some code if we should help you in any way) or the server might do something strange (maybe an empty result is expected when no server is present? We can't know that...)

Comment: To be more specific: So we need more information and I would also strongly suggested to talk to your client again. You don't need to look at the code, but you need some kind of API documentation. Or are you expected to guess other interfaces?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I've asked the client for any sort of documentation. I guess what I was asking, was just for confirmation that I'm not missing something stupid, and that I do actually need more details from the client. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What your client is suggesting is programmatically replicating the action of a user filling out the form at the address they provided.

To do that, try this:

```
var xmlData = '<xmlApi><action> getServerList </action><auth>xxxxxx</auth></xmlApi>';
var serverPath = 'http://some.com/path/';
var requestPath = 'xmlUserApi.php';
var request = $.ajax({
    url: requestPath,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { request: xmlData }
});
request.done(function(data) {
    /process data
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

//Leaving original answer down here

"You can send a POST request to the xmlUserApi.php named "request" by jQuery for example."

Not sure what they mean by 'named "request"', but with jQuery you would do this:

```
var serverPath: 'http://their.server.tld/path/';
var authToken: 'sometoken';
$.post(serverPath + 'xmlUserApi.php', { action: 'getServerList', auth: authToken },
   function(data) {
      //whatever you want to do with the return goes here
   }
);
```

There may also be an issue with the connection to the API, sometimes passing additional parameters helps with this, you could try:

```
var serverPath = 'http://their.server.tld/path/';
var requestPath = serverPath + 'xmlUserApi.php';
var authToken = 'sometoken';
$.ajax({
    url: requestPath,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { action: 'getServerList', auth: authToken }
}).done(function(data) {
    //processing here
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your code, I've edited it a little and added error handling, however, all that is alerted is "error". Do you have any ideas, thanks. http://pastebin.com/eUF0GZx0

Comment: That looks good to me, but probably now the clients API needs more input than what they have provided you. I am going to update my answer to something that may work as an alternative though.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. The error I'm getting from your updated code is a "parsererror". At least it's better than no error! Any thoughts?

Comment: are you able to use a browser inspector and look at the request? If so, try that and post the response in your question please.

Comment: I've added the response in my question. The response makes sense, since on at the PHP address, they have an HTML form set up for testing. This is what made me think I need more info from the client, but he is not willing to give it. Do you know what specifically I should be asking for?

Comment: If you browser to the URL that you are making a request to, there is a form on that page with a textarea, ask the client what exactly should go in that textarea (like if someone were using that form, what would they put in there)

Comment: The xml that I posted in my initial question is what is posted into the textbox to return a response

Comment: Ok, revising my answer now that I understand

Comment: This is still giving an error. The error alert just says "error" and the console is not showing any response.

Comment: Just updated example again. Forgot that cross domain you have to use "jsonp". If that doesn't work, I am not sure then.

Comment: This feels like an improvement, at least now in the console, it is returning XML with error 100, authentication error

Comment: Good! Yeah, that is the same result I was getting by manually filling out the form. That should mean the code is working properly now. I would ask your client to have a look at the xml you are passing and tell them the error you are receiving. Also, try manually filling in the form with the xml your are trying to pass and see if you get the same result. If you, the error is on the clients end.

Comment: Unfortunately the XML in the form does return a proper result (xml list of servers). I am wondering if the authentication error is due to the cross domain request. If I add "?request=" followed by the XML to the end of the URL, I get the same error however. I'm sure there must be something with the API the client is not telling me, they are making me feel like it 'should just work' and I feel like an idiot!

Comment: I'm also getting this error if I print out errorThrown:      jQuery110209200121955946088_1389203132831 was not called